# SOAP call works perfectly on local but doesn't work when in the server (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, soap

I developed a SOAP call on PHP (inside WordPress) which works perfectly on local (MAMP) but when I upload to a shared host  it doesn't work. The request's response is "Fail to connect to server(...)".

I tried to use the same PHP version and increase the server response time but it still doesn't work.

Funny part: two other related endpoints work, just a specific one doesn't.

A bit of my code:

[...]

```
    ob_start();
    error_reporting (E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);
    ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 60);
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

[...]

```
    $params = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:val="johndoe">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
        <val:SomeThing.Execute>
        <val:SomeThing2>'.$SomeThing2.'</val:SomeThing2>
        <val:SomeThing3>'.$SomeThing3.'</val:SomeThing3>
        <val:SomeThing4>'.$SomeThing4.'</val:SomeThing4>
        </val:SomeThing.Execute>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>';
    
    $ch  = curl_init();
    $url = $url_geral;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('autentica: /','Content-Type: application/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '600');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $output        = curl_exec($ch);
    $response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thats a call to cURL, not a soap call. Are you not using the [soapclient](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am only using cURL, indeed. But it still doesn't work on server.

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that soap library is installed on your webserver?

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('soap'));
```

And I think you should use build in soap client:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/webservices?wsdl");
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. Indeed I was/am using a cURL insted of SOAP, but the point is that my shared hosting was blocking the port.

I contacted them and they opened the proper door. Now it works.

Thanks to everyone who collaborated.